# How to add CSS link tag in header of NextJS 13 app

Tags: css, next.js, next.js13

I want to link to just a plain CSS file in my Next 13 app, but adding it to a Head component does nothing. I also tried creating a custom _document both in app and pages, and that also did nothing. What's the recommended way to do this in Next 13? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please see the following doc on importing global stylesheets - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/css-modules#external-stylesheets

Import global stylesheet from the `styles` folder:

```js
import "@/styles/global-stylesheet.css"
```

Import global stylesheet from npm package:

```js
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
```

> Note: External stylesheets must be directly imported from an npm package or downloaded and colocated with your codebase. You cannot use `<link rel="stylesheet" />`.

Comment: this is insightful thanks - what if we wanted to use the bootstrap CDN instead of the module? How can we add external stylesheets like this? <Link .. />

Comment: Next.js docs are pretty clear about this use case: External stylesheets must be directly imported from an npm package or downloaded and colocated with your codebase. You cannot use <link rel="stylesheet" />.

Answer (score 0):

First You can do like this:

1. Create your Head Component styles sheet with extension `Head.module.css`.
2. And import it in the `Head.js` component by using `import styles from "./Head.module.css` in `components` folder.
3. Make sure both files should be inside of `components` folder.

And that's all.

You can also refer this [CSS Modules](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/styling/css-modules#example) docs

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

if you have `global.css` for entire app, you can import it in `RootLayout`

```
import "./global.css";
```

If you want to import locally scoped css for each page, for example for `home` page, create `page.module.css`

and then import it

```
import styles from "./page.module.css";
export default async function Home() {}
```